# Geyser channel disconnects after the plugin loads

Tags: validator, geyser

I am trying to load a geyser plugin through patched validator of solana v1.18 and im having an issue where the `on_load()` method of the plugin fails because I get a channel disconnection error. This channel is reponsible for relaying `GeyserMessage` from the validator to the plugin for further processing when the plugin loads. Any idea why this might be happening?

Pretty sure somewhere deep down the Sender or Receiver is getting dropped but i'll provide the references down below:

- https://github.com/tinydancer-io/solana-proofs/blob/34cb8ef9304a53911a53f12952a6202a58afb606/account_proof_geyser/src/lib.rs#L310
- https://github.com/tinydancer-io/solana-1.18

[image: Logs]

Comment: As you mention, the receiver must be getting dropped somewhere, so be sure to add some logging in your receiver thread to see where it might be dying, to start with